# Array php percorrer

Tags: php, mysql, array, twig, silex

Para o array:

```
Array
(
    [45] => Array
        (
            [car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [consortiums] => stdClass Object
                (
        ),
    [92] => Array
        (
            [car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [consortiums] => stdClass Object
                (
        )
)
```

Como consigo percorrer todos os consórcios?

Comment: Não entendi o código, isso é um resultado do var_dump() ? sua dúvida talvez seja em como pegar os dois array ( com indice 92 e 25 ) pega pelo indice do primeiro array não resolveria ?

Comment: e isso mesmo, e eu me matando pensando que teria que capturar o array por aqueles numeros. vlw

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que essa estrutura se mantém, podes ir buscar com um simples **foreach**:

```
<?php

$consortiums = array();
foreach($arr as $arri)
    array_push($consortiums,$arri['car']->consortiums);

print_r($consortiums);

?>
```

Estou a iterar o array **$arr** (que representa o teu array), ignorando os índices numéricos, e para cada um acedo ao índice **car**, que devolve um objecto que tem o membro **consortium**, que por sua vez devolve o objecto final.
Repliquei o teu dump da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$ob  = new stdClass();
$ob->consortiums = new stdClass();
$ob->consortiums->i_am_a_consortium = "i am!";

$arr = array(
    45 => array("car" => $ob),
    92 => array("car" => $ob)
); 

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Que produz um output parecido com o teu (acrescentei apenas um membro ao último objecto, para percebermos que se tratam dos consortiums):

```
Array
(
    [45] => Array
        (
            [car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [consortiums] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [i_am_a_consortium] => i am!
                        )
                )
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [car] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [consortiums] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [i_am_a_consortium] => i am!
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

E testando o ciclo, o output é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [i_am_a_consortium] => i am!
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [i_am_a_consortium] => i am!
        )
)
```

Que é um array de consortium.

A tua questão é um tanto vaga, e não dá para perceber exactamente como pretendes o output, mas assim ficas com uma ideia.